# in sql, how to choose random time in from records having from and thru timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, intervals

have records, each having

```
pk_id  serial primary key,
key varchar(20),
...
from_ts timestamp(0) not null,
thru_ts timestamp(0) not null,
```

wish to choose random time from intervals as determined by `from_ts` to `thru_ts`

a record with a two hour interval should have twice as much chance of being selected as a record with a one hour interval.

records having the same key are disjoint - there are no overlapping times

wish to select the `pk_id` and the random timestamp.

```
select pk_id, ???
from rcds
where key = 'abc'
```

using `postgres`, so ANSI plus `interval` datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table rcds (
    pk_id  serial primary key,
    key varchar(20),
    from_ts timestamp(0) not null,
    thru_ts timestamp(0) not null
)
;
insert into rcds (key, from_ts, thru_ts) values
('abc', '2012-01-01 12:34', '2012-01-02 13:47'),
('abc', '2012-01-03 10:52', '2012-01-07 18:23')
;

with r as (
    select sum(extract(epoch from thru_ts - from_ts)) * random() as r
    from rcds
)
select 
    pk_id,
    from_ts + (
        ((select r from r) - coalesce(lag(ts, 1) over (order by from_ts), 0))
        ::text || ' seconds'
        )::interval as random_ts,
    from_ts
from (    
    select 
        pk_id, 
        sum(extract(epoch from thru_ts - from_ts)) over (order by from_ts) as ts,
        from_ts
    from rcds
    where key = 'abc'
) s
where (select r from r) <= ts
order by from_ts
limit 1
;
```

I'm assuming the timestamps are ordered by the pk_id. If not then it is just a matter of changing the ordering to the from_ts column.

---

Changedt it to order by the from_ts  column

---

New edition due to a better understanding of the question.

Comment: looks outstanding! the only I would change is to ordering by `from_ts` instead of `pk_id`.  really like how you set up `r` in the `with` clause.  the `select ... over` is quite nice as well.  testing.

Comment: you are returning `pk_id, ts`, but `ts` is the summed epoch through the record, not `r`'s offset into the interval in the record.  for example, if first and second records had intervals of one hour, and the `r` was an hour and a half, then the answer would be the pk of the second record (right) and half an hour past `from_ts` in the second record.

Comment: @ccyoung Changed to order by the from_ts column

Comment: @ccyoung Edited. I guess now I got it.

Comment: tested.  works great!  thanks again.  imho it's some outstanding sql.  one question: do not understand why you needed the `s0` select inside the `s1` select - could they have been combined into one?

Comment: @ccyoung Yes. Corrected. It was cruft left from some failed trial.